# How to drag a control on to a frame in vb5 form. (I am using windows XP)

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration, vb5

In my Visual Basic 5.0 form windows xp.  I can not drag an lable control onto a frame, thereby making the option specific to that frame. I can double click the label control and then move the option control over to the frame, but then the frame doesn't recognize the control as it's own.

I know I'm supposed to be able to drag controls onto the form, but for some reason I can't. A circle with a cross through it icon appears as my mouse symbol indicating I am not allowed to do this operation.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not drag a control onto a frame. You should insert the control onto the frame.
If you want to move an existing control to a frame simply select the control and `cut` (CTRL+X) it. Then select the frame and `paste` (CTRL+V). The control will now be inside the frame and cannot be moved outside of the frame.

If you create controls at runtime then use the `Container` property of the control to set it inside a frame.